# How to receive broadcasts when other apps are opened or closed

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I want to receive a broadcast intent in my app when other apps are opened or closed or just put aside by pressing the back button.Is there any broadcast intent to do that?

Comment: your app should not be able to determine which app is launched or stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `Intent`s that are broadcast for this. You will need to use the `AccessibilityService` to do this.